# Where to call a for loop in to iterate through an array of values

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a javascript function that i am using to scrape.I am using it with Puppeteer. If I am using one value, it works, but if i introduce a `for` loop for it to iterate through an array of values, it fails. I'd like to know what the right place to introduce the for loop would be.

This is my working basic script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var listOfURLs = [url1, url2,url3,url4,url5]
let scrape = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(listOfURLs[0]);

  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let title = document.querySelector('#innerLeft > div.dspPropertyTitle > h1').innerText;
    return {
      title
    }

  });

  browser.close();
  return result;
};
scrape().then((value) => {
  console.log(value); 
});
```

my URLs are contained in the the variable `listOfURLs`. If I manually reference listOfURLs[0], as in the example above, it works just fine. Now I want it to loop through the whole array and access values as listOfURLs[i], so I tried this and it didn't work. I don't know what is wrong.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');    
var listOfURLs = [url1, url2, url3, url4, url5]
for (i=0; i<=listOfURLs.length; i++) {
  let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(listOfURLs[i]);

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let title = document.querySelector('#innerLeft > div.dspPropertyTitle > h1').innerText;
      return {
        title
      }

    });

    browser.close();
    return result;
  };
  scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); 
  });
}
```

Comment: I would advise you to change your approach,let the asyc/await finish it's work before you move on the next iteration. You can put your code in a function and return the array from there and then iterate it over. :-)

Comment: I think your problem is `i<=listOfURLs.length` in for loop

Answer (score 1):

`i` is hoisted, and `scrape` is async - after a `scrape` `await`s at the very beginning, the `for` loop will have finished, so `i` will become `listOfURLs.length + 1`, which means accessing `listOfURLs[i]` later won't work.

Use `let` instead, so that each iteration has a separate binding for `i`.

You also should test `i < listOfURLs.length`, not `i <= listOfURLs.length`, because `i < listOfURLs[listOfURLs.length]` will be undefined:

```
for (let i=0; i < listOfURLs.length; i++) {
```

But these sorts of `for` loops are pretty ugly and are frequent sources of problems like this - you might consider `forEach` instead, which has better abstraction, has function scope (is composable) and doesn't require manual iteration, if you're OK sending requests in parallel:

```
listOfURLs.forEach(async (url) => {
  const scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const title = document.querySelector('#innerLeft > div.dspPropertyTitle > h1').innerText;
      return { title };
    });
    browser.close();
    return result;
  };
  scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); 
  });
});
```

(another option using array methods is `reduce` if you want to make requests in serial)

Comment: This worked, but I am not sure i understand your statement about "requests in parallel". Do you mean if I have 5 URLs in my array it's opening 5 different browser instances? If that is the case, then this might not be a scalable solutions. That array is a list of search results urls. So they may be 2, they may be 100. Opening 100 parallel instances would be ugly in terms of memory. I just want a smooth running solution, even though it might be slower.

Comment: You could use `for..of` if you wanted. `for (const url of listOfURLs) {` and `await` inside each iteration to run in serial

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably stemming from the fact that you're making asynchronous calls inside the for loop. You want a result before you move on to the next one, and since it's asynchronous your code isn't going to wait for a response and continue onto the next url in the array.